# Android asks to re-enter WiFi passwords. Is my phone compromised?

Tags: security, malware, wifi-password

I have a Galaxy S8 (SM-950F) with Android version 8.0.0. I have rooted the device with Magisk. I have a couple of Magisk modules, including Bixby remapper, F-Droid Privilaged Extension, liboemcrypto disabler, libsecure_storage companion, and Cloudflare DNS.

Recently I realized I have to re-enter my password for all WiFi networks even though the passwords are the same.

Is this simply a corrupted WiFi password file case (I have no Idea how the software on this phone manges passwords) or it could be that the phone is somehow compromised and some malware is forcing me to re-enter passwords in order to log them?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Not sure it's really a malware. Since your phone is rooted, it would be trivial for malware to read the file where the Wi-Fi passwords are stored, given it's in plaintext.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Good point. Where can I find this database?

Comment: On Pie, the location should be `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`. On older Android versions, it used to be `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`.